# Updating store inside ngrx effects is not synchronous

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

In a component when I update the store synchronously with a new value and then get it just after I get the updated value.

```
const updatedValue = 1;
this.store.dispatch(updateCounter({ counter: updatedValue }));
this.store
  .pipe(select(selectCounter), take(1))
  .subscribe((v) =>
    console.log(
      v === updatedValue
    )
  );
```

console.log displays true

On the other hand if I copy the same code inside a ngrx effects

```
loadData$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(triggerEffect.type),
  tap(() => {
    const updatedValue = 1;
    this.store.dispatch(updateCounter({ counter: updatedValue }));
    this.store
      .pipe(select(selectCounter), take(1))
      .subscribe((v) =>
        console.log(
          v === updatedValue
        )
      );
  })
```

console.log displays false.

Why ? (Stackblitz repro https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s59777?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/my-counter/my-counter.component.ts)

Comment: It’s an interesting question. What I do know is that internally, ngrx assures certain orders of operations, for example, if a reducer and and effect listen to the same action, the reducer is guaranteed to run first. Not sure of this is related, but I can imagine it has something to do with that behavior maybe?

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/eslint-plugin/rules/no-dispatch-in-effects

Comment: Have you tried testing this more than once? Maybe your assumption (about the first one being synchronous) is incorrect? 

What I've noticed is that reducers with trigger asynchronously and they won't reflect the order of dispatched commands. 

What do you want to achieve anyway? Subscribe with async pipe to the selector on your view/html and it should be updated any time new value is updated by reducer in your store.

Comment: This behaviour is known. But on the other hand, there is no reason to implement a manual subscription within an effects.

If you need to select a state value, just use `concatLatestFrom` https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/operators#concatlatestfrom

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to rewrite the Effect as flowing:

1. Use `map()` instead of `tap()`, because `tap()` can only return the same source value in time you need to return a deferent value, so `map()` can do that.
2. Return the action instead of dispatching it.

   ```js
   loadData$ = createEffect(() =>
     this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(triggerEffect.type),
       map(() => { 
         const updatedValue = 2;
         console.log('we will dispatch ' + updatedValue);
         return updateCounter({ counter: updatedValue })
       })
     )
   );
   ```
3. And change the code in `MyCounterComponent` to and move the selector to it:

   ```js
   updateWithEffects() {
     this.store.dispatch(triggerEffect());
     this.store
       .pipe(select(selectCounter), take(1))
       .subscribe((v) =>
          console.log(
            v === 2,
            'the value in the store is the same as the dispatched value'
          )
        );
   }
   ```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjtkuh?file=src/app/my-counter/my-counter.component.ts